# Video Upload from dropbox to vimeo server

Tags: javascript, php, dropbox-api, vimeo-api

We want to fetch video content(only) from multiple dropbox to our vimeo account(single) both from  password protect and without any password dropbox link. Let us know the procedure and relevant libraries in Java,JS or PHP.

Below is more detail

// Successful uploaded by this url

**$url='http://domainname.com/band.avi';**

// dropbox url which failed
**$url='https://www.dropbox.com/s/filepath/abc.avi';**

Methid Used:

> $response = $lib->request('/me/videos', ['type'=>'pull','link'=>$url],
>   'POST');

Error Message received

```
[body] => Array
        (
            [error] => Unable to locate a video at the provided link
        )

    [status] => 400
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your second link looks like a Dropbox share link. Those links go to web pages on the Dropbox site (so they contain HTML). To turn one of those into a link directly to the content, use the technique described at https://www.dropbox.com/help/201: add `?raw=1` as a query parameter.